# How can an Azure Service Bus message in a topic subscription queue exceed it's delivery count when the Azure Function triggered by the queue is down?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

We have an Azure Function on the consumption plan. It is triggered by a topic subscription queue. The Azure Function sometimes is stopped and started again. We know this because we see it in our logs: "Stopping JobHost" and "Starting JobHost" respectively. There was some time between these log messages: about 40 seconds. An Azure Service Bus message was delivered to the queue during this time. This message ended up in the dead letter queue. The reason was "MaxDeliveryCountExceeded" and its delivery count was 11.

This happens intermittently, about once or twice a week. Other than this, the Azure Function behaves exactly as expected. Logging works, messages are handled, etc. Even in the minutes before and after the time window described above the Azure Function was behaving perfectly.

There was no deployment during this time. (There was a deployment a few days before, and a few days after.) There is no other application triggered by this topic subscription queue, not in Azure, and not on our own machines (we use a separate Azure Service Bus namespace for development.)

Why did the message not cause the Azure Function to start again? And how did the delivery count go up during this time?

Possibly related issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/164

host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "redacted": "Information"
        }
    },
    "retry": {
        "strategy": "exponentialBackoff",
        "maxRetryCount": 5,
        "maximumInterval": "00:01:00",
        "minimumInterval": "00:00:03"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your host.json configuration and the subscription settings? I wonder if a paused function means the the code that is not yours and responsible to fetch messages is also paused.

Comment: I added the contents of host.json. Regarding the code that is responsible for fetching messages: the message ends up in the dead letter queue with reason max retries exceeded, so I think something does fetch the message but is not able to deliver it because the job host is stopped, and does not log this in a way that we are able to see it.

Comment: Seems to be the case. Azure support is what I’d try as you have no control over the receiving aspect.

Comment: If you don't have the support plan then please let me know so we can connect offline to verify the backend logs to know what was happening during that time.